# How to check if a gameObject has a particular property?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Player object with a `public boolean isIndestructible = true` property. I also have a Mine object that has the following function:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !other.gameObject.isIndestructible) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
}
```

Basically, I only want the game to reload if the Player object is not indestructible. However this code doesn't work (`gameObject` doesn't have `isIndestructible` as a property), so what's the proper way to find this?

Comment: `isDestructable` is not a property, but a field. That being said make it a property and also declare it in an interface which is implemented by all classes having this property. So you just need to check if an object is from this interface and use the interfaces property, e.g.`var objectIsIndestructable = (other.gameObject as IHaveIsIndestructible)?.IsIndestructable`. You could use reflection, but that’s bad design.

Comment: You would have to use `GetComponent` to get the script associated with the desired property/field/method.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Player object with a public boolean isIndestructible = true property.

So you have already attached a `MonoBehaviour` to the Player object, right?

**Player.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isIndestructible {get; set;}
}
```

To get the property `isIndestructible` in `Mine`,

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    var player = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();
    if(player != null && player.isIndestructible){        
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gave me a StackOverflowException error when trying to run the game. I put `[HideInInspector]` in front of the isIndestructible declaration, as well as `Player player = new Player );` in the Player class so I can set `player.isIndestructible = true` in `private void Start()`. What did work for me without using get/set was `Player player = other.gameObject.GetComponent (typeof(Player)) as Player;` and then checking `player.isPunching`.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan Please test your script with a minimal unit test. BTW, don't use `GetComponent (typeof(Player))` because `typeof(Player)` uses reflection and is quite slow. Use `GetComponent<Player>()` instead.